# How to calculate Shapley value when order matters?

Tags: r, game-theory, shapley-value

I am trying to figure out the Shapley value when order matters.

When using the R package `GameTheoryAllocation` you have to input the characteristic function.

For example if there are 3 players 1, 2, 3 one has to input the following coalitions:

```
[1] "0"          
[2] "'{ 1 }'"    
[3] "'{ 2 }'"    
[4] "'{ 3 }'"    
[5] "'{ 1,2 }'"  
[6] "'{ 1,3 }'"  
[7] "'{ 2,3 }'"  
[8] "'{ 1,2,3 }'"
```

But what if `{1,2}` is different than `{2,1}` how should I specify this?